# How do I share my apps open graph object using the new Share Dialog with the Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Recently I received an email from facebook stating the the Share Dialog now supported posting Open Graph objects, but the link they provided only shows an example using the iOS sdk. From what I can tell, the same functionality is available in Android SDK and JavaScript SDK, but I haven't found examples that show an apps open graph object included.

I already know how to post an open graph object to a users wall. What I would like to do is use the new share dialog and post my OG Object using that.